# ¿Cómo comparar una rama local de git con su rama remota?

Tags: git

¿Cómo puedo ver la diferencia entre una `rama local` y una `rama remota`?

Comment: con el comando `git diff`

Comment: Para hacerlo debes primero hacer `git fetch`, luego como indica @JackNavaRow, `git diff rama_local rama_remota`. Saludos

Comment: solo por señalarlo, recuerda que antes debes hacer un `git fetch` para taerte los cambios de las ramas, no vaya a ser que intentes comparar con un remoto no sincronizado y no veas diferencias...

Answer (score 1):

El comando `diff` te permite hacer comparaciones, un ejemplo de de lo que quieres.

```
git diff master origin/master
```